# What kind of CLT is this? Can I prove it using Lindeberg-Levy CLT?

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, regression, estimation, central-limit-theorem

On deriving the asymptotic distribution of an estimator, I got stuck when proving something like follows:

Let $\{X_i(\beta):i=1,2,\ldots,n\}$ be i.i.d. with $\text{E}[X_i(\beta)]=\mu(\beta)$ and $\text{Var}[X_i(\beta)]=\sigma^2(\beta)$, then by Lindeberg-Levy we have
$$
\sqrt{n}[X_i(\beta)-\mu(\beta)]\overset{A}{\sim}\mathcal{N}[0,\sigma^2(\beta)].
$$
However, we don't know what $\beta$ is, and thus we must find some estimator for that. Now, assume that we have some estimator for $\beta$ that follows $\hat\beta\overset{p}{\to}\beta$. Then it sure follows that $\text{E}[X_i(\hat\beta)]=\mu(\hat\beta)\overset{p}{\to}\mu(\beta)$ and $\text{Var}[X_i(\hat\beta)]=\sigma^2(\hat\beta)\overset{p}{\to}\sigma(\beta)$. My question is whether it still follows
$$
\sqrt{n}[X_i(\hat\beta)-\mu(\beta)]\overset{A}{\sim}\mathcal{N}[0,\sigma^2(\beta)]
$$
or not? In other words, is this $X_i(\hat\beta)$ still an efficient estimator for $\mu(\beta)$? Can I use Lindeberg-Levy or Khinchine's WLLN to prove it? I've tried for some hours but with no idea. It's just an intuition.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

---

Also, if you'd like to look into the original problem directly, please go to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192573/asymptotic-distribution-of-the-ls-estimator-using-an-extra-ratio-of-the-coeffici).